# Windows Phone WebBrowser injecting using local file?

Tags: javascript, css, windows-phone

I am trying to inject a web page using my JS file. The following is my injecting code:

```
string script = "var jsDoc=document.createElement('script');jsDoc.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');jsDoc.setAttribute('src', 'http://saudiairlines.s3.amazonaws.com/js/updateV1.js');document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jsDoc)";

MyWebBrowser.InvokeScript(SCRIPT_NAME, new[] { script });
```

What I need now is putting JS file locally and inject the page,

Please note, the JS file contains links to another files in my local folder.

Comment: TypeError: Failed to execute 'askQuestion' on 'Stackoverflow': 1 question required, but only 0 present.